# How many multiples of 3 are in $100!$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

I know that $100!$ is $100\times99\times98\times...2\times1$ but I don't get how to get all the factors of three from this. Help!

Comment: How many multiples of three are there less than 100?  How many multiples of $9$?  How many multiples of $27$?  How many multiples of $81$?

Comment: Start small.  How many factors of $3$ in $10!$ what is the pattern?  Can you prove that the pattern holds as the numbers get bigger?

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't think so. The process is the same but the question is a different one, that question reduces to figuring out the 5-adic valuation of 100! whereas this one is the 3-adic valuation

Comment: @qbert the theorem cited in the answer applies **directly** to this question as well

Comment: @JMoravitz that may be, but we don't close every question that uses the mean value theorem

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Every multiple of 3 introduces a factor 3 (like 30, 96), how many of those numbers are there in 100!
- Every multiple of 9 introduces an additional factor 3 (like 36, 99), how many?
- Every multiple of 27 yet another one, and every factor 81 even one more.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the 3-adic valuation of 100!, which is given by the Legendre formula 
$$
\lfloor \frac{100}{3} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{100}{3^2} \rfloor+....\\
=33+11+3+1=48
$$

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do here is to calculate the highest power of $3$ contained in $100!$. It can be easily calculated using [de polignac's formula](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8iZrVltHQAhXBr48KHQDMCi8QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDe_Polignac%27s_formula&usg=AFQjCNEe_WfHWmh0piO8l2SplUqlzOzw_A&sig2=A4GHzITTjYebRgLyNVreYg).

For your question it looks like $[\frac{100}{3}]+[\frac{100}{9}]+[\frac{100}{27}]+[\frac{100}{81}]=48$

Answer (score 0):

$$\color\red{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\lfloor\log_{3}{100}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{100}{3^n}\right\rfloor}=\left\lfloor\frac{100}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{100}{9}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{100}{27}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{100}{81}\right\rfloor=33+11+3+1=48$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not conventional way to think of it but... it might help:

$100! = \prod_{k=1}^{100}k$

$=100*\prod_{k=1}^{99}k$

$=100*\prod_{k=1}^{33}3k*\prod_{j=1}^{33}(3j-1)*\prod_{l=1}^{33}(3l-2)$

$3\not \mid 100*\prod_{j=1}^{33}(3j+-1)\prod_{l=1}^{33}(3l-2)$

so $100!$ and $\prod_{k=1}^{33}3k$ have the same power of $3$ factors.

$\prod_{k=1}^{33}3k=3^{33}\prod_{k=1}k$

$= 3^{33}*\prod_{k=1}^{11}3k*\prod_{j=1}^{11}(3j-1)\prod_{l=1}^{11}(3l-2)$

$3\not \mid \prod_{j=1}^{11}(3j-1)\prod_{l=1}^{11}(3l-2)$

so $100!$ and $3^{33}\prod_{k=1}^{10}3k$ have the same power of $3$ factors.

$3^{33}\prod_{k=1}^{11}3k = 3^{33}3^{11}\prod_{k=1}^{11}k$

$=3^{33}3^{11}*11*10*\prod_{k=1}^33k*\prod_{j=1}^3(3j-1)*\prod_{l=1}^3(3j-2)$

And again $3 \not \mid 10*11*\prod_{j=1}^3(3j-1)*\prod_{l=1}^3(3j-2)$ so

$100!$ has same power of $3$ factor of $3^{33}3^{11}\prod_{k=1}^33k$

$3^{33}3^{11}\prod_{k=1}^33k= 3^{33}3^{11}3^{3}\prod_{k=1}^3 k$

$3^{33}3^{11}3^{3}*1*2*3$ and $3 \not \mid 2$ so

$3^{33}3^{11}3^{3}*3 = 3^{33+11+3+1} = 3^{48}$ is the highest power of $3$ that divide $100!$.

In other words $\lfloor 100/3 \rfloor=33$ of the integer terms of $1*2*3....*98*99*100$ are multiples of $3$ so $3^{33}|100!$.  Of those $33$ multiples of $3$ one third of them are multiples of $9$ and so on.